# JPA query couldn't find the right constructor

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

So basically I try to get some data of a User by its ID and it has a field with @OneToOne relationship(bidirectional)

When I try to create a query in JpaRepository
with @Query annotation

```
@Query("SELECT new com.project.model.user(u.id, u.username, u.profile.last_online, u.profile.about) FROM User u WHERE id = :id)
```

and a constructor

```
User(long id, long username, Profile profile) {
   this.id = id;
   this.username = username;
   this.profile = profile;
}
```

it still can't really find the constructor and says that there is no "matching constructor", is there a way to create the constructor better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor you expect in your query has `(long, String, Timestamp, String)`. And your constructor takes `(long, long, Profile)`.

So you need to create a matching constructor:

```java
public User(long id, String username, Timestamp lastOnline, String about) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.profile = new Profile(lastOnline, about); // create new Profile with lastOnline & about
}
```

This should work.

But may I ask why you're not using the `JpaRepository#findById(Long id)` method?

Comment: The reason I'm not using findById is that I need only certain values, as the userEntity is heavy, this was just an example of the problem in my question. anyway, I think this.profile = new(stuff) solved the problem, as I was confused about how to create the constructor properly in this situation. Thanks

Comment: @TheCrunchyPotato Note that you can also make your `User` class a JPA entity and simply make it an read-only/immutable object. There's nothing that limits you to one entity class per table.